# Does the added component (intended to disturb equilibrium) always ends up being more than the original amount, in the new equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium

The title can be a little unclear. But what I am basically saying is say we add a reactant to a reaction to push the reaction forward toward the product side, that reactant which was increased in amount/ concentration will surely less. Part of it used to produce more products to gain new equilibrium. **But will it always be more than the original amount in the equilibrium before?**

Without knowing much of advanced math, I just experimented with some simple fractions; thus far I haven't seen anything that violate this rule.

Comment: Are you considering Le Chatelier's principle ? And do you mean "increased in amount/concentration will surely _become_ less" ?

Comment: Yes la chatier. What I meant was the component of a reaction that is being increased in amount to push the reaction in either one of the two directions.

Comment: Is the amount of component always gonna to be more at the new equilibrium than was originally.

Comment: Okay , got it now . Its a very good question and the answer is Not Always . I am giving you a hint to think about : "What happens if there are only a solid and a gas in the reactant side ? Write down the eqn and calc Eq. Const expression for each case " . If you get it from here well and good . If not , I will answer the question .

Comment: Did you get it then?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get it.